# Pyplot plotting different linestyle and marker style while plotting an 1d column vs nd column

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a long code which plots 12 boxes of figures where in each box there are many curves. So its important for me to keep code clean since its a big code just for generating one figure. what exactly I am doing is that

```
ax[0,0].plot(data1[:,0], data1[:,[1,2,3,4,5]], linewidth=1);
ax[1,0].plot(data2[:,0], data2[:,[1,2,3,4,5]], linewidth=1);
ax[2,0].plot(data3[:,0], data3[:,[1,2,3,4,5]], linewidth=1);  
ax[0,1].plot(data4[:,0], data4[:,[1,2,3,4,5]], linewidth=1);  
ax[1,1].plot(data5[:,0], data5[:,[1,2,3,4,5]], linewidth=1);   
ax[2,1].plot(data6[:,0], data6[:,[1,2,3,4,5]], linewidth=1);
.        
.     
.
6 more lines.
.       
.
```

For the legend I am doing something like

```
ax[0,0].legend(labels=['line1','line2','l3','l4','l5'])
```

Now my question is is there way way I can tell pyplot to use different linestyle, markerstyle, linecolor, markercolor, from a list? Something that I could do for the legend using the option labels=list. It's better if I can do it inside the plot command.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#

Comment: @swatchai sorry if I wasn't clear. I am not looking for any solution related to legend. I am looking for a way that will tell pyplot to use different linestyle markerstyle and color for the plotting of each column in that datan array.

Comment: I suggest spending some time with the [matplotlib tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html). There is also [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html) and [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-marker-reference-py) in the example gallery.